# how to draw a rect with diagonal lines with konva or svg.js and the lines is even spacing fill the rect

Tags: svg, canvas, svg.js, konva

`*The Scenes:*`

I use konva to draw a diagonal line in a rect,
the rect api fillLinearGradientColorStops meet my need ,
when the value of fillLinearGradientColorStops Array length is smaller **200**,the line is normal ,
but when length become bigger than 200, the lines become different color ,some lines is dark red some other is light red;

how to fix this error to make  when length is **1000** the diagonal line color is same

`core code`

```
// get linear gradient step---start
const colors = []
const length = 500
Array(length).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
    /**
     * a rect is split into 10 parts, from 0 to 0.1 to 0.2 to 0.3 ...1;
     * i only want set color is red in 0.1,0.2,0.3 and...0.9 ,and other is #fff,
     * so i use a arr to store the result.
     * if the length is bigger the red line is thinner,smaller gradient
     */
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    colors.push(index * 0.002, arr.includes((index * 0.02)) ? "red" : '#fff')
})
// get linear gradient step---end

// draw a rect
const layer = new Konva.Layer();
const rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 120,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 200,

    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {
        x: 100,
        y: 200
    },
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: colors,
    stroke: "black"

});
```

the array length is more bigger ,when near the interpolation the linear gradient is become smaller,the line will thinner

`when length is 500,the result`

[image]

`bigger length make smaller gradient`

[image]

[image]

how to get a normal red line or all red is the same color

Comment: Your sample code looks overly complex. Please make a more simple example that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat hello i edit my question,add some comment,my english is poor ,hope dose not make your confused; if you has some other advise,tell me ,i will do my best;thx

Comment: I still do not understand your question.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat [this is a sample with detail code](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-chatelet-x6pzd4?file=/src/index.js); my question is why the left diagonal is even but the right is uneven?

Comment: in chrome the line uneven  is a issue ,in safari and firefox is even

Answer (score 0):

```
There is nothing much we can do from the Konva side. This is how the browser renders it. You can compare results in Firefox and Safari. You will see it is different from Chrome.

I think some of your lines get lighter because their size is too small.
```

this answser is come from konva core developer,then I test the same code in safari and firefox,i found the result is same.

Comment: for some konva beginner, can use other api :*fillPatternRepeat:repeat*,then set a image to fill the rect,but the rect should be a square with many diagonal line ,it will repeat from left to right and top to bottom ,have a same result but without uneven error in chrome,the svg.js is same ,but the api is pattern,you can search in the doc